# Why does this git/grep/vim shortcut bash code not work as advertised?

Tags: linux, bash, git, vim

At the end of this bash tutorial [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEN4WnFNMx0) ,Spencer Krum shows a neat hack: how to open a file in vim at the line number where an immediately preceding 'git grep -n' search string was located.  It seemed neat, but his code does not work as described on two different linux boxes I tried it with.  It just always opens a blank file.  [original code here](https://github.com/nibalizer/bash-tricks/blob/master/bash_tricks.sh#L101)

My steps:

First, I made sure to have git initialized and files inside the directory to grep for.  For example, I had a somefile.txt with three lines of words:

- its
- a
- mystery

Then I ran: `git init;git add .; git commit`

Then, modify your .bashrc file to redefine vim as shown below.  Make sure to source the .bashrc file when complete:  `source ~/.bashrc`

Finally, run the git grep -n command with a search term you know is in a file in your git directory that is your current working directory.  Finally, run vim.  It should open your file with the cursor at the search term line.  But it doesn't: `git grep -n mystery;vim`

```
#Spencers Original
vim () {
    last_command=$(history | tail -n 2 | head -n 1)
    if [[ $last_command =~ 'git grep' ]] && [[ "$*" =~ :[0-9]+:$ ]]; then
        line_number=$(echo $* | awk -F: '{print $(NF-1)}')
        /usr/bin/vim +${line_number} ${*%:${line_number}:}
    else
        /usr/bin/vim "$@"
    fi
}
```

To get the desired result, I had to simplify the regex in the second clause of the first if statement, and also create some temp variables to run additional eval logic on.

Below is my revised code:

```
#My revised version
vim () { 
    last_command=$(history | tail -n 2 | head -n 1)

    rempws="${last_command#*"  "}"
    remtws="${rempws%*" "}"

    file_name="$(eval $remtws | awk -F: '{print $(NF-2)}')"
    line_number="$(eval $remtws | awk -F: '{print $(NF-1)}')"

    if [[ $last_command =~ 'git grep' ]] && [[ $line_number =~ [0-9] ]]
    then
        /usr/bin/vim +${line_number} ${file_name}
    else
        /usr/bin/vim "$@"
    fi
}
```

Is this related to a bash update since 2015?  I don't think it's git related, as my git grep -n command does return a string in the form 'somefile.txt:3:mystery'.  Everybody in the audience loved it, and it's still on github on the non-functioning form, so I am worried that I am missing something fundamental about bash.

Show me why I'm dumb.

Comment: I don't think you're the one who is dumb here. Just don't use such junk code on your production environment.

Comment: And really, if you're bopping around a repo like this, just install the fugitive plugin, it does amazingly nice things with e.g. `:Git grep` and so many other git commands.  For instance, say `:Git blame` while you're editing a tracked file. Its docs will repay basically any amount of time you put in to them.

Comment: `$ vim -q <(git -n mystery)` parses the output of `git grep`, creates a `:help quickfix` list, and places the cursor on the first match. You would be better off starting from standard features than copy-pasting magic scripts.

Comment: @oguzismail - don't worry, this was just an exercise I went through because this technique was highly acclaimed by the conference attendees, so I thought I was missing something.  Now I'm mostly confused about why he would debut useless code at a conference - and with the pride of a recent nobel winner.

Comment: I'm not so much concerned with figuring out a more efficient solution that my own revision, than i am trying to gain consensus on whether or not he actually presented broken code at a conference and I'm not crazy for not being able to get it to work out of the box.

Comment: @romainl I especially appreciate your approach.  It's the simplest and most flexible so far.

Comment: From what I understand, the author is using his function like this: 1. do `$ git grep -n foo`, 2. copy `path/to/filename.ext:23:` from the results, 3. do `$ vim `, 4. paste `path/to/filename.ext:23:`, 5. press enter. If used that way, his function works predictably as-is.

Comment: @romainl Yes, you are correct that following those steps solves the problem.  But if you watched the video (link in post), he certainly does not explain it like that.  He earned his applause because it is a clever solution.  But if he really intended on  copying and pasting hardcoded results, why not just have 3. do ```$ vim +```, 4. paste only ```23 ``` and then 5. paste only ```path/to/filename.ext``` before pressing enter.  This way, he would never have to even write a new vim function in .bashrc in the first place.  It's not efficient if you build ad-hoc commands from copy-paste each time.

Comment: I agree, the applause doesn't seem warranted, here. That makes for a clunky workflow. On a related note, I would suggest taking a look at [git-jump](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/git-jump) (and [this slight modification](https://gist.github.com/romainl/a3ddb1d08764b93183260f8cdf0f524f) that I have yet to submit upstream) for opening various Git "things" in Vim: `$ git jump grep foo`.

Comment: Agree with others that this is a hack and there are much better solutions (`vim -q`, using vim-fugitive plug-in, etc.) But to address why this didn't work for you: If what you were running was `git grep -n mystery;vim`, then this function wouldn't work, since it depends on the `git grep` being a command of its own, just before the vim call. So you had to execute `git grep -n mystery`, press "Enter", then run `vim`.

Comment: @filbranden 's comment (just above mine) has the answer, but I'll note one more thing here: searching for a particular function or variable or whatever really calls for tags or similar. There is a bunch of ongoing work (including good stuff actually coming out of Microsoft) to make this work better in vim in the future...

Comment: @filbranden and @torek - I actually did run the ```git grep -n mystery``` command, then pressed enter, then ran ```vim``` separately afterwards.  I often  group multiple lines of code into a semi-colon separated one-liner when I post on forums just to keep the length down to a minimum.  Lesson learned though - best to remove all ambiguity.  Anyways, executing vim as a standalone command certainly did not solve the problem for me.  Did you find different results?

Comment: Looking at the original I'm not even sure how it's supposed to work since it looks it's only getting the `git grep` *command* from history, the output is actually not even in history, so how would it get it? Your revised command is running it twice (once for filenames, other for line numbers), furthermore I don't see how you'd handle `git grep` returning multiple results... In any case, I agree with others that this is for the most part not a good idea. Learn to use the quickfix feature, it's actually meant for this exactly and it's properly designed and not a hack...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally understood what this is about.

His code was never really meant to somehow access the output of the `git grep` command.

Instead, it's a realization that after a `git grep` you're likely to want to open one of the results.

But, in his workflow, he still relies on copy & paste of the `git grep` results into the Vim command-line.

The only difference is that, right after a `git grep`, you can pass Vim a filename with a line number separated by `:` rather than having to pass two separate arguments.

In his example, the result of `git grep` started with:

```
CHANGELOG.rst:75: ...
```

So, if at the next command you execute:

```
$ vim CHANGELOG.rst:75:
```

(Assuming you copied the last part from the `git grep` results.)

Then the bash function would trigger this command instead:

```
$ vim +75 CHANGELOG.rst
```

Which will open this file on line 75.

If you like the idea of this feature, a much cleaner way to implement that is to install and enable the [bogado/file-line](https://github.com/bogado/file-line) Vim plug-in, which implements support for that kind of filename + line number arguments in Vim itself.

(Also, there's really no good reason to *only* recognize the `file:line` syntax right after a `git grep`. If you want that behavior, it's better to always get it, not just sometimes. It should be consistent.)

An even better alternative is to use the [quickfix](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html) feature of Vim, which was conceived for exactly this kind of situation. You can either set `'grepprg'` manually, to invoke `git grep` with the appropriate arguments, or you can adopt a plug-in such as [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive), which implements a `:Ggrep` command that calls `git grep` and presents the results using the quickfix list.

As pointed out by @romainl, you might also want to look into [`git jump`](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/git-jump), which is a git command you can enable on your system to have git find interesting locations (such as `git grep` or `git diff` output) and have git itself open those results in Vim (using the quickfix list when appropriate.)

Comment: He says *"Did you give me something with colon-linenumber-colon?"* But he's talking about **you** the user giving that as an argument, not *you* (it?) `git grep` giving Vim anything... I can see how it sounds like the code magically accesses the output of `git grep`, but looking at the code, what it's looking at is the arguments passed. In the video, he also says *"So whenever I type 'vim'"* and implying he's typing *just* `vim` with no arguments, but again looking at the code it's not the case.

Comment: I think it got a lot of applause because it *sounded* way more magical than it actually was.  I'm guessing the audience also took it as it was somehow parsing the `git grep` output. Since it was a powerpoint and not a live demo, we couldn't see how it actually worked in practice. But, again, looking at the code, it's evident that `$*` (argument passed to the function) is where it's looking for a colon-linenumber-colon, so that info had to get there somehow, presumably by a copy and paste.

Comment: Watch the last 30 seconds of the video I provided in the original post? [link_at_correct_time] (https://youtu.be/pEN4WnFNMx0?t=263)  Based on his description, it would make no sense if the solution required manually copying and pasting the output of the previous command.   It's less than 30 seconds, let me know what you think.

He says:   

"I overwrited vim so that whenever I type 'vim', it says 'was the last command you typed 'git grep'?  did you get something with ':linenumber:'?  if so, i'll open up that file to the line number that matched your most recent grep!' "